# Skipping loop with end row determined by cell value that also loops

Tags: excel, loops, vba

******SOLVED******
What im trying to do is have a formula calculate every 47 rows to a range which the end is determined by a cells value.

I have tried using If statements - case variables and many other tweaks however i am at a loss.

The code is to add a index match formula starting at row 200 to the last count for each person. The count for each person is totaled in row M and starts at row 190 and also skips every 47 rows

I am trying to get the loop to enter a comment if the value of M is 0 and the formula to be entered down as many rows as the value of M

```
'Sub LOGVOIL()
'FIND  VIOLATIONS


Dim lastRow As Long, I As Long
Dim LR As Integer
Dim FR As Integer
Dim addall As Integer, addone As Integer

FR = 10
lastRow = Range("P190").End(xlDown).Row
For I = 190 To lastRow Step 47
     LR = Range("M" & I).Value
     addone = I + FR ' adds 10 rows to the start postion of the loop starts at row 200
     addall = I + LR ' adds the end row count to the end of the loop
If (LR = 0) Then ' if the value of M is 0 then we enter a comment on the first row of the loop
    Set dlv = Range("a" & addone)
        With dlv
           .Value = "No Violations"
        End With
Else ' any other value we add a formula to the end of the count
    Set dlv = Range("A" & addone & ":A" & addall) ' range here be a200:a202 if the count of m was 2
        With dlv
                .Formula = _
                    "=IFERROR(INDEX(RDBMergeSheet!E:E,MATCH(""log""&K197&"" ""&M197,RDBMergeSheet!$N:$N,0)),"""")"
                .forumla = .Value
        End With
End If
'*********************************************
' tryed using cases
 'select Case LR
    'Case 0
        'Set dlv = Range("a" & addone)
       'With dlv
      '    .Value = "No Violations"
     'End With
    'Case Else
        'Set dlv = Range("A" & addone & ":A" & addall)
         '   With dlv
         '       .Formula = _
         '           "=IFERROR(INDEX(RDBMergeSheet!E:E,MATCH(""log""&K197&"" ""&M197,RDBMergeSheet!$N:$N,0)),"""")"
         '       .forumla = .Value
        'End With
'End Select
Next I
```

End Sub`

The case select work but only for 0 here is how it runs

[current outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpQCY.png)

I think that i have a simple error in the code, However im at a loss any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

I was able to figure it out 
here is the working code

`Sub logvil()
Dim lastRow As Long, I As Long
Dim LR As Integer, cr As Integer, FR As Integer
Dim addall As Integer, addone As Integer
    ' starts at row 200
    lastRow = Range("P190").End(xlDown).Row
    For I = 190 To lastRow Step 47
         FR = 10
         LR = Range("M" & I).Value
         cr = LR + FR
         addone = I + FR
         addall = I + cr
   Select Case LR
        Case 0
     Set dlv = Range("a" & addone)
           With dlv
              .Value = "No Violations"
         End With
        Case Else
             Set lv = Range("A" & addone & ":A" & addall)
                With lv
                    .Formula = _
                        "=IFERROR(INDEX(RDBMergeSheet!E:E,MATCH(""log""&K197&"" ""&M197,RDBMergeSheet!$N:$N,0)),"""")"
                    .Formula = .Value
            End With
    End Select
    Next I
End Sub`

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what you're trying to do here. Could you add some sample data to your question and, if you can, a 'before' and 'after' example?

Comment: `forumla` --> typo. Are you using `Option Explicit`?

Comment: @ A.S.H i had the Formula .value commented out but i did notice the misspelling. and with the case select option it only works with the case 0 after that everything starts at the first line in the loop. here is what it should look like . 
  
      
skips down 47 row to row 237      
   3  person has 3 items 
      
      
formula    <  row 247  
formula   stops after 3 rows from value in M237   
formula

Comment: You haven't actually stated exactly what is your problem.

Comment: Sorry timed out --@ A.S.H  i did notice the misspelling and with the case select option it only works with the case 0 after that everything starts at the first line in the loop.  -- do i need the Option explicit on this? 
here is how it is suppose to work
@ Ambie Loop starts by looking at the value in M190 this gives the number to add to the loop count within the with statement for the last row to add a formula in (A200:a & count of M190) then skips 47 rows and loops again

Comment: I have added a picture and some more information to the original post